# Carry out a mysql function before exiting a page

Tags: javascript

I want the page to update the mysql database whenever the admin exits the page.
This is a timeline of events:

users submit assignments and The administrator would select a script to mark, when the admin opens the script (in a mark.php page), the page would update the database that someone is marking that particular script and when the admin exits the mark.php page, the page should automatically update the database to show nobody's marking the page.

i created a column in the database to show if someone is marking the script or not, if so it would enter the administrator's user id into the column, and when the admin exits the page it should remove it.

The function to update the database before exiting the page isn't working.

This is what i have

```
<script>
function exitmarking()
{
return "dsds";

    <?php
$connect->executeQuery("UPDATE assignment_submit SET markedby='' WHERE assignment_submit_='$asid'");
?>
}
</script>
```

and the html

```
<body onbeforeunload="return exitmarking()"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is server-side code, the database query would always be executed before the user ever sees the page rendered - no matter how you structure the location of the PHP code in the page (within your Javascript event).

What you can do is a separate PHP page to do the UPDATE query, and then on exit, use Javascript to do an AJAX call (either native or Jquery or whatever framework you prefer) in your marking javascript function.

Comment: so instead of using php code in the exitmarking() function i just make an ajax call in the function?

Comment: exactly. that will make the update only run when the ajax call is made.

Comment: am trying this `function exitmarking()
{
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open("GET","test.php");
    
       a.send();
}` and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: this also isn't working    `var request = $.ajax({
   url: "test.php",
   type: "GET",   
   dataType: "html"
  }); `